# how to Submit two datetime values from ASP.NET Core form

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having an issue with an ASP.NET Core form i made, it consists of submitting two datetime values from the same form. I have a period object looking like this:

```
public class PricePeriod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PeriodStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime PeriodEnd { get; set;}
}
```

and then the razor html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="editNewPeriod" asp-action="SavePeriod" asp-controller="Administration" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="REPLACE-WITH" data-ajax-update="#newPeriodDialog">
                <label>Id: </label> <input type="text" id="PeriodId" name="PeriodId" value="@Model.Id" style="color:grey;" readonly></br>
                <label>Navn: </label> <input type="text" placeholder="@Model.NamePlaceHolder" value="@Model.Name" name="Name" /></br>
                <label for="PeriodStart">Fra: </label> <input value="@Model.StartDate" asp-for="PeriodStart" class="datepicker" />
                <label for="PeriodEnd"> Til: </label><input asp-for="PeriodEnd" value="@Model.EndDate" class="datepicker" /></br>



        <input type="submit" value="Gem" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //Functions to control range-picking
    $(function(){

        initializeDatepickers();
    });

    function initializeDatepickers(){
        var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy",
        from = $("#PeriodStart")
        .datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            showAnim: "blind"
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        }),
        to = $("#PeriodEnd")
        .datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            showAnim: "blind"
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
            from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
        });

        function getDate( element ) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }

        return date;
        }

    }
```

Now, everything here seems to work, except that when i submit, the PeriodEnd of the object when i submit, it's just the same as DateTime.MinValue, and i can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here. I tried doing the HTML by writing out all the attributes of the input tag of PeriodEnd myself, but that did not change a thing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What culture is your server configured to use? Try sending dates as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: I'm using da-DK which means it's configured as: DD/mm/yy